# Bigquery uncommon elements in array

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let us say you have a column of arrays like this  , I am trying to group the rows based on the count of uncommon elements. Once the number of distinct uncommon elements reaches 5, it will be in the next group.
In the below example, first three rows will be group 1 because the uncommon elements are ['3','4','6','7']  which is 4 in length, but if you add the next row to the group , the array of distinct uncommon element would be ['1','3','4','5','6','7'] it will exceed the limit of 5 distinct uncommon elements.

```
with arr as (
       select 1 ord, ['1','2','3','4'] as ar
       union all 
       select 2, ['1','2','3']
       union all 
       select 3,['1','2','6','7']
       union all 
       select 4,['2','4','5','7']
       union all 
       select 5, ['string1','5','6','7','8']
      )

      select * from arr
```

I am looking for an output like below

[image]

Code I have written so far but definitely missing a big piece. Adding it just in case if it is helpful

```
with arr as (
       select 1 ord, ['1','2','3','4'] as ar,1 subclass
       union all 
       select 2, ['1','2','3'],1
       union all 
       select 3,['1','2','6','7'],1
       union all 
       select 4,['2','4','5','7'],1
       union all 
       select 5, ['string1','5','6','7','8'],1
      )
, history_t as (
      select a.* ,
     ARRAY_AGG(struct(ar)) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBCLASS ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as history
  
      from arr a ) 

, tem2 as (

 select a.* except(history,ar), 
 
 (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(history) AS col ) AS array_cnt
 ,b.ar unnest1
 from history_t a
 ,unnest(history) b 

) 

, tem3 as (
select a.* except(unnest1),sku_lst
from tem2 a , unnest(unnest1) sku_lst
) 

, all_sku_freq as (
select 
ord, array_cnt , sku_lst , subclass,count(*) sku_freq
 from tem3
 group by 1,2,3,4 ) 

, uncommon_sku_cnt as (
 select ord, subclass, count( sku_lst) uncommon_sku_count from all_sku_freq where sku_freq <> array_cnt group by 1,2 ) 

 ,rolling_uncomm_sku_cnt as (

select a.*, sum(uncommon_sku_count) over(partition by subclass order by ord asc range between unbounded preceding and current row  ) roll_uncomm_sku_cnt 
from uncommon_sku_cnt a
 ) 

 select a.* from rolling_uncomm_sku_cnt a
```

Comment: I have many questions here. 1) you say 'next row ...' - what defines order of those rows so you can identify which row is next?

Comment: added an order column, does it look better?

Comment: 2) should rows in groups be consecutive rows or any rows in a table?

Comment: if any rows in table would make it super complicated, i would take just the consecutive rows

Comment: 3) provide more info about your data - like how many rows in table, what is the max size of array in the column, how many distinct elements in total, etc. 4) also would be interesting to understand what kind of the real use case behind this abstraction

Comment: 3) 100k rows, max size of an array will be 5000, 10k distinct elements

Comment: 4) I have buckets and some elements in each bucket, I want to group the buckets together if the elements in it are <=3 elements different. This is one piece to solving that bigger problem. All the questions you have been helping lately is for this

Comment: Ok. Thank you for clearing my questions. I will look into this o:)

Comment: awesome, thank you!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I have been trying out something but definitely not writing something dynamic enough. I can post the code i have so far, if you are still interested in this problem. your opinion will be very helpful!

Comment: I looked into your case and was not able to find generic way of addressing it. I do think, the final solution will heavily depend on what exact data you have how it is distributed and so on. In another word without having access to the actual data and being able to profile it, play with it, etc. there is no way (at least for me) to help you.  Also, your case looks to me too abstracted which makes it hard to come up with any workaround - so I feel like I am pass in this case :o(  P.S. but this still looks interesting to me so I will be checking this post time to time :o)

Comment: I understand what you are saying, thanks for taking a peek!! :)

Comment: I think you are trying to build a house with only one shovel. You should use python and scipy lib to finish this.

Comment: I wanted to keep it all in SQL because my original dataset is huge, but if you have ideas in python I can take it too!